# How to Remove or hildent all Default event & property in userControle

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll, user-controls

Remove all Default event & property 
Remove event Click,Load,MouseClick,DoubleClick in userControle
or hildent event

```
    public event EventHandler Click
    {
        add { this.Click += value; }
        remove { this.Click -= value; }
    }
```

Error !!!>>>An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.dll

this image sample
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJADh.png)

Comment: can you at least show the error?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try *overriding* them and tagging them not browsable.

Here is an example with `Click` event :

```
[Browsable(false)]
public new event EventHandler Click
{
    add { base.Click += value; }
    remove { base.Click -= value; }
}
```

Comment: Thank God for Saving me